# Android studio Logcat showing an error message "null' and after that stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, adb

I am facing an issue from last few days in Android studio. It seems to be an ADB or IDE related issue. Each time this popup shows, Logcat stop working. I am not able to track crashes and other outputs.

[image]

I tried Invalidating Cache & Restart and Restarting system but not successful.

Here is some detail of Android studio:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Please update your android studio or Reinstall**

1. Open the **Preferences** window by clicking **File > Settings** (on Mac, **Android Studio > Preferences**).
2. In the left panel, click **Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates**.